# ReCaptcha - Use of the same keys in several files

Tags: security, key, recaptcha

I received my security keys (client and server) to use in my website. I have two versions of my form, a French and an English located in the same directory. The client has to choose for one of the two versions.
Can I use the same key for both versions, or should I request different keys for each version of my form?
The French version is working very well, but the English version is rejected.
How should I solve this ?
Thanks for your reply.